# If $\frac{\sin^3 x -\cos^3 x}{\sin x - \cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2x}}-2\tan x \cot x=-1$ where $x\in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

If we solve the above expression, it’s very clear that the equation doesn’t depend upon x. Then all that is left to is to get 
$$\sin x -\cos x \not =0$$
$$x\not = \pi /4, 5\pi/4$$
But the answer given is $$x\in (0,\pi)-{\pi/4,\pi/2}$$
What is the reason for leaving so many values out ie. $\pi , 2\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\frac{\sin^3 x -\cos^3 x}{\sin x - \cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2x}}-2\tan x \cot x=-1$$

$$\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}}}-2=-1$$

$$\sin x\cos x-|\sin x|\cos x=0$$

which is always true for $\sin x\ge 0$ otherwise it is true for $x=0,\frac \pi 2, \frac{3\pi}2,2\pi$.

Therefore, since we also need $x\neq \frac \pi 2,\frac {3\pi} 2$ for $\tan x$ and $x\neq  0,2\pi$ for $\cot x$ all the solutions are given by $x\in (0,\pi)$ with $x\neq\pi/4$ and $x\neq \pi/2$.

Comment: The solutions are searched, and correctly found in $[0,2\pi]$, I believe...

Comment: @dfnu As the question was formulated, I was assuming it was an identity, I din't check it. I fix that part. Thanks

Comment: I didn’t get why $\sin x>0$ and why the modulus was applied

Comment: @Aditya Recall that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ that is $x$ for$ x>0$ and $-x$ for $ x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

The square-root is positive, so you need $\sin x\gt0$

Comment: @user the square-root of $1+\cot^2x$ in the denominator

Comment: The square-root is the absolute value of $\csc x$, so if $\sin x\lt0$ the second term is $+\cos x\sin x$ instead of $-\cos x\sin x$

Comment: @Empty Yes now I've realized you observation!